A sci-fi movie about an orb that gives people powers
I'm trying to identify a movie with the following details:

It's a sci-fi movie about an alien spacecraft on the bottom of the ocean.
They find a large orb that gives them powers.
They inadvertently manifest their fears.
At the end, they all decide to use their powers to forget how to use them.
It stars Samuel Jackson.

Saw it years ago and can't remember the name! Thanks.

There's really not enough to go on, but my guess is that it's Sphere (1998).

An alien spacecraft is discovered on the floor of the Pacific Ocean,
  estimated to have been there for nearly 300 years. A team of experts,
  including marine biologist Dr. Beth Halperin (Stone), mathematician
  Dr. Harry Adams (Jackson), astrophysicist Dr. Ted Fielding
  (Schreiber), psychologist Dr. Norman Goodman (Hoffman), and U.S. Navy
  Capt. Harold Barnes (Coyote), are assembled and taken to the Habitat,
  a state-of-the-art living environment located near the spacecraft. 
...
The mini-sub makes it to the surface as the surface ships return. As
  Beth, Harry, and Norman begin safe decompression, they realize that
  they will be debriefed and their newfound powers discovered. They all
  agree to erase their memories of the event using their powers; this
  assures that the "unknown event" paradox is resolved. The sphere rises
  from the ocean and then accelerates off into space.


By jove i think he's got it! Thank you.
